# How to Detect Shapes in Images in Python using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, detect

I'm trying to read the shapes in the image and print them to my array, but I can't succeed. It doesn't form exactly correctly.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

shapes=[]
img = cv2.imread('objects.png')
img = cv2.resize(img,(500,500), fx=0,fy=0)
imgGry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret , thrash = cv2.threshold(imgGry, 240 , 255, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours , hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thrash, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01* cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    x = approx.ravel()[0]
    y = approx.ravel()[1] - 5
    if len(approx) == 3:
        shapes.append("Triangle")

    elif len(approx) == 4 :
        x, y , w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        aspectRatio = float(w)/h
        print(aspectRatio)
        if aspectRatio >= 0.95 and aspectRatio < 3.05:
            shapes.append("Square")

cv2.imshow('shapes', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()    

print(shapes)
```

It should give the number of pictures as output `[Square,Triangle,Square,Triangle,Square,Triangle]`

Comment: What result do you get? Show your resulting image. Are there errors?

Comment: Actually I didnt take error but I take wrongly output.==>Output is ['Square']

Comment: `img10` is not defined, what is this ?

Comment: img10 changed img

Comment: What results do you get in `approx` (how many contours, how many points per contour, etc.)? Did you try `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`? Why are you using the constant `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` in `threshold()` rather than `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`?